# Use of Linear fixed-effects models with non-normal distribution (A histogram is added)

Tags: r

I have two questions .

Using R, I would like to use a linear fixed-effects model to predict a score (range 0 to 3). Each participant received two scores (so data are repetitive).

But the score distribution is non-normal.

[image: Data distribution]

**Question 1**: In this case, is it okay to use a LME model? Or should I use a generalized linear mixed-effects (GLME) models? If so, could you recommend an R package, and help me find which GLME should be used?

**Question 2**: When creating a LME model, I had 95 predictors, so I had this error message:

> "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 93 columns /
>   coefficients Error: Dropping columns failed to produce full column
>   rank design matrix"

How I can fix this error?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome! You're more likely to get an answer about to your first question on the statistics stack exchange site, [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). And for your second question, could you edit your question to include the data and code the created the error?

Comment: Q1: The assumption is that once the parcelling out to subgroups within strata of  "random effects" that the _residuals_ of the subgroup regessions will be approximately normal. The only way you can test that is to do the regression first and then examine the residuals. You canNOT make that assessment by just looking at raw data. Q2 .... there should be no Q2. Multipart questions are deprecated.

Comment: linear regression doesnt look like a good choice: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238581/how-to-use-ordinal-logistic-regression-with-random-effects might be an option or have a search on mixed-effects multinomial

Comment: Thank you so much!!